# Is the median or mean of a set of values in Decibels (dB) taken directly or conversion to linear is required

Tags: mean, median, data-conversion, decibel

I need to take the median of a set of values of path loss (dB) in MatLab. Does anyone know that they shall be converted to linear units like Watts before their median is calculated by the formula. The result is different in both the cases but i don't know which one is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The median is just the middle number if you were to line them up in ascending or descending order.  It should give the same result if you convert to a linear scale or if you keep it as dB.

However, if there are an even number of values, then it will make a difference and you should probably stick with the linear values.

Comment: If there are an even number of samples, there won't be a "middle" number, in which case you normally would average the two bracketing values.  So linear vs. nonlinear scaling might still make a difference.

Comment: Ah yes, that is true!